# collection filter error on shopify based online store

Tags: html, css, ruby, shopify, shopify-template

I am working on a already developed theme on shopify based online store.there is a issue related to filter..it is showing multiple tags for same option like in size filter it is showing 2XL and XXL both..i am not able find glitch in code.kindly help me solve this.

'''
{%- endcomment -%}

```
  {%- if show_filters -%}
    {%- comment -%}
    Implementation note: the filters can be displayed in two different ways: in a sidebar menu, always visible, or in a drawer. Due to that, we are
    setting the general code here, and then we will output it twice.
    {%- endcomment -%}

    {%- assign quick_links = linklists[section.settings.filter_menu] -%}

    {%- capture filters_content -%}
      {%- if quick_links != empty -%}
        <div class="Collapsible Collapsible--padded Collapsible--autoExpand">
          <button type="button" class="Collapsible__Button Heading u-h6" data-action="toggle-collapsible" aria-expanded="false">
            {{- quick_links.title | escape -}} <span class="Collapsible__Plus"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="Collapsible__Inner">
            <div class="Collapsible__Content">
              <ul class="Linklist">
                {%- for link in quick_links.links -%}
                  <li class="Linklist__Item {% if link.active %}is-selected{% endif %}">
                    <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="Link Link--primary Text--subdued {% if link.active %}is-active{% endif %}">{{ link.title | escape }}</a>
                  </li>
                {%- endfor -%}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- if has_visible_tags -%}
        {%- if section.settings.filter_mode == 'tag' -%}
          <div class="Collapsible Collapsible--padded Collapsible--autoExpand">
            <button type="button" class="Collapsible__Button Heading u-h6" data-action="toggle-collapsible" aria-expanded="false">
              {{- 'collection.filter.all' | t -}} <span class="Collapsible__Plus"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="Collapsible__Inner">
              <div class="Collapsible__Content">
                <ul class="Linklist">
                  {%- for tag in collection.all_tags -%}
                    {%- if tag contains '__' -%}
                      {%- continue -%}
                    {%- endif -%}

                    <li class="Linklist__Item {% if current_tags contains tag %}is-selected{% endif %}">
                      <button type="button" class="Link Link--primary Text--subdued {% if current_tags contains tag %}is-active{% endif %}" data-tag="{{ tag | handle }}" data-action="toggle-tag">
                        {{- tag -}}
                      </button>
                    </li>
                  {%- endfor -%}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        {%- else -%}
          {%- assign groups = '' -%}

          {%- for tag in collection.all_tags -%}
            {%- assign tag_parts = tag | split: '_' -%}

            {%- if tag_parts.size != 2 -%}
              {%- continue -%}
            {%- endif -%}

            {%- assign groups = groups | append: tag_parts.first | append: ',' -%}
          {% endfor %}

          {%- assign color_label = 'color,colour,couleur,colore,farbe,색,色,färg,farve' | split: ',' -%}
          {%- assign groups = groups | split: ',' | compact | uniq -%}

          {%- for group in groups -%}
            {%- assign group_downcase = group | downcase -%}

            {%- if color_label contains group_downcase and section.settings.show_filter_color_swatch -%}
              {%- assign show_color_swatch = true -%}
            {%- else -%}
              {%- assign show_color_swatch = false -%}
            {%- endif -%}

            <div class="Collapsible Collapsible--padded Collapsible--autoExpand">
              <button type="button" class="Collapsible__Button Heading u-h6" data-action="toggle-collapsible" aria-expanded="false">
                {{- group | escape -}} <span class="Collapsible__Plus"></span>
              </button>

              <div class="Collapsible__Inner">
                <div class="Collapsible__Content">
                  <ul class="{% if show_color_swatch %}ColorSwatchList HorizontalList HorizontalList--spacingTight{% else %}Linklist{% endif %}">
                    {%- for tag in collection.all_tags -%}
                      {%- assign tag_parts = tag | split: '_' -%}

                      {%- if tag_parts.size != 2 or tag_parts.first != group -%}
                        {%- continue -%}
                      {%- endif -%}

                      {%- if show_color_swatch -%}
                        <li class="HorizontalList__Item">
                          {%- assign color_swatch_name = tag_parts.last | handle | append: '.png' -%}
                          {%- assign color_swatch_image = images[color_swatch_name] -%}

                          <button type="button" class="ColorSwatch {% if current_tags contains tag %}is-active{% endif %}" data-tag="{{ tag | handle }}" data-action="toggle-tag" data-tooltip="{{ tag_parts.last | escape }}" style="background-color: {{ tag_parts.last | replace: ' ', '' | downcase }}; {% if color_swatch_image != blank %}background-image: url({{ color_swatch_image | img_url: '64x64' }}){% endif %}">
                            <span class="u-visually-hidden">{{ tag_parts.last }}</span>
                          </button>
                        </li>
                      {%- else -%}
                        <li class="Linklist__Item {% if current_tags contains tag %}is-selected{% endif %}">
                          <button type="button" class="Text--subdued Link Link--primary {% if current_tags contains tag %}is-active{% endif %}" data-tag="{{ tag | handle }}" data-action="toggle-tag">
                            {{- tag_parts.last -}}
                          </button>
                        </li>
                      {%- endif -%}
                    {%- endfor -%}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endif -%}
    {%- endcapture -%}

    <div id="collection-filter-drawer" class="CollectionFilters Drawer Drawer--secondary Drawer--fromRight" aria-hidden="true">
      <header class="Drawer__Header Drawer__Header--bordered Drawer__Header--center Drawer__Container">
        <span class="Drawer__Title Heading u-h4">{{ 'collection.filter.all' | t }}</span>

        <button class="Drawer__Close Icon-Wrapper--clickable" data-action="close-drawer" data-drawer-id="collection-filter-drawer" aria-label="{{ 'header.navigation.close_sidebar' | t }}">
          {%- render 'icon' with 'close' -%}
        </button>
      </header>

      <div class="Drawer__Content">
        <div class="Drawer__Main" data-scrollable>
          {{ filters_content }}
        </div>

        <div class="Drawer__Footer Drawer__Footer--padded" data-drawer-animated-bottom>
          <div class="ButtonGroup">
            <button type="button" class="ButtonGroup__Item Button Button--secondary" data-action="reset-tags" {% if current_tags == blank %}style="display: none"{% endif %}>{{ 'collection.filter.reset' | t }}</button>
            <button type="button" class="ButtonGroup__Item ButtonGroup__Item--expand Button Button--primary" data-action="apply-tags">{{ 'collection.filter.apply' | t }}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}

  {%- if section.settings.show_sort_by -%}
    <div id="collection-sort-popover" class="Popover" aria-hidden="true">
      <header class="Popover__Header">
        <button class="Popover__Close Icon-Wrapper--clickable" data-action="close-popover">{% render 'icon' with 'close' %}</button>
        <span class="Popover__Title Heading u-h4">{{ 'collection.sorting.title' | t }}</span>
      </header>

      <div class="Popover__Content">
        <div class="Popover__ValueList" data-scrollable>
          {% assign collection_sort_by = collection.sort_by | default: collection.default_sort_by %}

          {%- for option in collection.sort_options -%}
            <button class="Popover__Value {% if option.value == collection_sort_by %}is-selected{% endif %} Heading Link Link--primary u-h6" data-value="{{ option.value }}" data-action="select-value">
              {{ option.name }}
            </button>
          {%- endfor -%}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}

  {%- comment -%}[enter image description here][1]
```

'''
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epQsN.jpg

Comment: You need to edit and create a specific stream regarding the options name and make sure you follow the standard of them, not have duplicate data like Colour or color and Size and size.